# How to pass variable name in subprocess command

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.call('"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Install Exe\\download.exe" /S norestart ', shell=True)
print(result)
```

This is something hardcode in the command, I want to pass this path in the variable and want variable instead of the path

Can we do this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
subprocess.run(["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"])
```

so say I wanted to move a file from "/home/myfile.txt" to "/home/data" which accepts the arguments sourcefile and destination folder I would do

```
subprocess.run(["mv", "/home/myfile.txt", "/home/data"])
```

any of these strings can be variables and the strings can be f-string formatted also

Comment: import subprocess
source_url="https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.1.9.2/npp.8.1.9.2.Installer.exe"
destination=f'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Install Exe\\download.exe'
download =urlretrieve(source_url,destination)
result = subprocess.call('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Install Exe\\download.exe /S norestart ', shell=True)
print(result)

how to write a variable name in subprocess command instead of hard code path

Comment: @RishiVashishtha, this answer tells you to stop using `shell=True` and instead pass a list of individual arguments. You can use a variable for any of those arguments.

Comment: @RishiVashishtha if this answers you're question would you mind accepting it please